# Why am I receiving a 401 Unauthorized in my C# ASP.net MVC Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2, sharepoint-2013, http-status-code-401

I have a C# asp.net MVC project, that will be used as a Web API to call SharePoint 2013 endpoints. I have gone ahead and configured SharePoint with a developer site, added the proper app information to both the App.manifest and web.config files in the project, registered the app with the SharePoint site, and created/set up a certificate for the Token Issuer. As far as I can tell, and yes I've checked a few times, that all the proper info has been entered in the proper locations.

The code I'm trying to run is as follows:

```
[SharePointApiControllerContextFilter]
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/testapi/search/{id}")]
public System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult<string> Search(string id)
{
    var spContext = SharePointApiControllerContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(ControllerContext);
    string data = string.Empty;

    using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
    {
        if (clientContext != null)
        {
            try
            {
                string url = spContext.SPHostUrl + "_api/search/query?querytext='" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(id) + "'";
                Uri uri = new Uri(url);

                HttpWebRequest searchReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
                searchReq.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";

                String username = "username";
                String password = "password";
                String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));

                searchReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);

                HttpWebResponse results = (HttpWebResponse)searchReq.GetResponse();
                var stream = results.GetResponseStream();

                var readStream = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
                var content = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                return Json<string>(content);
            }
            catch (WebException we)
            {
                return Json<string>(we.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                return Json<string>(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    return Json<string>(data);
}
```

Within IIS on the server, only Basic Authentication, ASP.net Impersonation, and Forms Authentication are enabled.

Everything seems to be set up correctly, but with my basic auth request, I always get a 401 unauthorized response from SharePoint. I've also noticed the actual API endpoint is endlessly redirecting when being visited from a web browser directly.

Would somebody help me fix my issue(s) with the API and the endpoints? Thanks.

Comment: The 401 you're getting is when calling `_api/search/query` or when calling `api/testapi/search`?

Comment: @FabioLima The 401 is when I call the full URL, so I assume _api/search/query, however, in a web browser, the API just redirects endlessly, regardless of my code.

Comment: Have you tried using RestSharp instead of HttpWebRequest and check if it returns the same error?

Comment: @FabioLima Using the RestSharp library returns the same 401 error.